# SASS - Compass not found

Tags: sass, compass

I just switched over to using Windows Command Line Sass. I had been using apps like Scout and Compass.app to compile. SASS is running fine and will compile, but when I use `@import "compass"` it breaks and I get the error:

"Error: File to import not found or unreadable: compass."

I'm pretty sure I installed Compass correctly when installing SASS. The only thing I can think of that could be breaking it would a pathing issue to compass, perhaps? Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, there were two things I was doing wrong:

1- I was using `sass --watch file.scss:file.css`. I should've been using `compass watch`
2- I was watching the wrong folder. I needed to go up a directory.

I would delete this, but hopefully it will help someone someday. If you're having this problem, also make sure Compass and Sass are installed correctly where they should be.